# content_for vs yield in partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

In rails 3.0 with HAML (3.1.4) I have

1. some template-like *partial*, like _template.html.haml:

   ```
   .panel.top
     = yield :panel_top

   .content
     = yield
   ```
2. some another *partial* which will be displayed using prev template (all this stuff is rendered using AJAX, but this doesn't matter)

   ```
   - content_for :panel_top do
    .title.left
      = title

   content text
   ```

and this worked like a charm in Rails **3.0**

*But, after upgrade to **3.2** this fails! Yiels just yields "content text", so I have "content text" twice and no title at all*

only changing `= yield :panel_top` to `= content_for :panel_top` works for 3.2

I am not sure that this solution is ok, and if it is stable or recommended, I cannot find any notes about changes in `yield` processing nor in Rails 3.1 release notes, nor in 3.2 ones.

Can you help what is the best way to organize `yield`ing inside partials?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.2 `content_for` was really changed:

**3.0**:

```
def content_for(name, content = nil, &block)
    content = capture(&block) if block_given?
    @_content_for[name] << content if content
    @_content_for[name] unless content
end
```

**3.2**:

```
def content_for(name, content = nil, &block)
  if content || block_given?
    content = capture(&block) if block_given?
    @view_flow.append(name, content) if content
    nil
  else
    @view_flow.get(name)
  end
end
```

This shows us, that from 3.2 `content_for` works for showing/inserting content too, not only store it for named section.

Also, if you make an attempt to debug `yield` logic you'll se that it yields before `content_for` is correctly initialized.

So, leaving fragment caching out of this discussion I can conclude that `content_for` is *preferrable* way to insert named sections anywhere except top-level layouts. In helpers and other situations `yield` should render wrong results.