# Rails: Content_for in partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeview

I have something like this in my layout

```
...
<%= yield :test %>
...
<%= render :partial => 'user/bar' %>
```

And in user/bar.html.erb I have

```
<% content_for :test do %>
stuff
<% end %>
```

And this doesn't seem to work. And I have found out that `yield :test` executes before partial, but after executing the view of the action. Why does it do so and what can I do?

Comment: Check this answer for a working solution (rails >= 3.2): http://stackoverflow.com/a/10440291/219589

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax `content_for :test do ... end` captures the content of the block, and `content_for :test` gives the captured block. [doc for content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for).

In your code, the restitution is done before the capture, so it cannot work.

Comment: Yes, I understood this. But how can I make rails use another boot sequence? Or maybe there is another solution. I want to have the opportunity to render more than one peaces from my partial.

Comment: @Ximik Maybe you can put `stuff` in its own partial, so it can be called both by the layout and by `user/bar.html.erb`

Comment: It really seems to be the best solution in this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote the partial into a local variable *before* calling `yield`, and then rendered it into the document later:

```
...
<% partial = render(:partial => 'user/bar') %>
<%= yield :test %>
...
<%= partial %>
```