# Just upgraded from 3.0.7 to 3.2.8; Partials not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded from 3.0.7 to 3.2.8 and a bunch of partials are not being displayed.  However, they are being rendered (according to the logs), and no error message is given.  Here's a (simplified) example:

**layouts/application.html.haml**

```
(snip)
%body
  = yield :header
  = yield
(snip)
```

**home/index.html.haml**

```
- content_for :head do
  (snip)

- content_for :header do
  (snip)

= render(:partial => "home_content", :layout => "shared/layouts/content_columns")
```

**shared/layouts/_content_columns.html.haml**

```
%div
  .content
    = yield :content_column
  .sidebar
    = yield :sidebar
```

**home/_home_content.html.haml**

```
- content_for :content_column do
  = render_external("twitter")
  = render(:partial => "seo_content")

- content_for :sidebar do
  = render(:partial => "featured")
  = render(:partial => "testimonials")
  = render(:partial => "social")
```

All the content for `:head` and `:header` is displayed, while none of the `:content_column` or `:sidebar` content is.  I figure something changed with rendering partials with layouts, but some quick searching didn't yield anything obvious.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's the rendering order from the logs (including debug statements I included in `shared/layouts/_content_columns.html.haml`):

```
Rendered home/_twitter.html.haml (1.4ms)
Rendered home/_seo_content.html.haml (0.9ms)
Rendered home/_featured.html.haml (2.2ms)
Rendered home/_testimonials.html.haml (2.1ms)
Rendered home/_social.html.haml (213.8ms)
DEBUG: String="Rendering shared/layouts/content_columns"
DEBUG: String="At '= yield :content_column'"
DEBUG: String="At '= yield :sidebar'"
Rendered home/_home_content.html.haml (256.9ms)
Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (300.6ms)
```

As you can see, the partials are being rendered before `home_content` and `index`, so their content should be grabbed by the `= yield` in `layouts/application`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to change `shared/layouts/_content_columns.html.haml`:

```
%div
  .content
    = content_for :content_column
  .sidebar
    = content_for :sidebar
```

Thanks to this SO question: [content_for vs yield in partials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185344/content-for-vs-yield-in-partials)